# How can a picture array within another array from a set of arrays be used with a swipe gesture?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, xcode

Complicated wording for something that is relatively simple. Where is an array of pictures defined if, it itself is a particular array item?

I have a set of arrays which are passed through a tableView to a DetailedViewController. One of which is images. On this DetailedView I would like to be able to implement a swipe gesture on a UIImageView so I can swipe through what essentially is an array of images inside of a particular array item.

PseudoCode:

```
Array 1:
array1-string1
array1-string2
array1-string3

Array 2:
array2-string1
array2-string2
array3-string3

Array 3:
array3-picture1
array3-picture2
array3-picture3
```

Each array stores a different set of data corresponding to the position in the array. eg: `Array1` is all the names, `Array2` is all the descriptions, `Array3` is all the pictures.

The detailedView displays one set of data. eg. `array1-string1, array2-string1, array3-picture1.`

Correct me if i'm wrong but in order to use the swipe gesture (for a particular set of data) I need an array of images as the `array3-picture1` item.

Would I specify this array when I initially declare all the arrays, in order for it to be hooked to an IBAction on the final detailedViewController, keeping in mind that this is called on a specific segue to the tableView. 
**OR**
Simply declare the array as just an array at the start and specify the values of it somewhere else.

Sorry if that makes no sense, but dealing with this has been doing my head in!

Answer (score 0):

I'd begin by considering this input data as not yet in object form.  You can create an NSObject subclass or a dictionary grouping related data.  For example (using dictionary):

```
NSMutableArray *objects = [NSMutableArray array];
NSAssert(array1.count == array2.count == array3.count, @"arrays must be of equal length");

NSInteger count = array1.count;
for (NSInteger i=0; i<count; i++) {
    NSDictionary *d = @{ @"name": array1[i], @"description": array2[i], @"image": array3[i] };
    [objects addObject:d];
}
```

This objects array can be the model for your table view, maybe presenting the names at the top level.  Upon selection, segue to a detail view, passing data like this:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"DetailSegue"]) {
        MyDetailViewController *vc = segue.destinationViewController;
        NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        vc.object = self.objects[selectedIndexPath.row];
    }
}
```

Then the detail vc does it's business by referring to the public property which I assumed in the above to be called object.  e.g.:

```
self.descriptionLabel.text = self.object[@"description"];
```